# How to create a record in a polymorphic association with multiple types of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise, polymorphic-associations

I have polimorphic associations for multiple types of users, `admin` and `original_user`.

I need to create  a user registration with all attributes of the related models, but I can create only the ID of the record in a related table, for example, Admin or OriginalUser.

How can I do it if I have nested attributes?

When debugging my code in the terminal, I saw:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :admin_attributes
```

and `sign_up_params` has only

```
{"email"=>"ush@gmail.com", "password"=>"123456", "password_confirmation"=>"123456", "meta_type"=>"admin"}
```

without `admin_attributes`.

Attributes for admin are `"degree_access"`(integer), `"department"`(string).

Attributes for original user are `first_name`(string), `last_name`(string) and `team`(string).

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :meta, polymorphic: true, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meta
end
```

app/models/admin.rb:

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
end
```

app/models/original_user.rb:

```
class OriginalUser < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user, as: :meta, dependent: :destroy
end
```

app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_action -> { request.session_options[:skip] = true }
    before_action :configure_sign_up_params

    KEYS_FOR_SIGNUP = %i[
    meta_type
    email
    password
    password_confirmation
    [ admin_attributes: [ :degree_access, :department] ]
    [ original_user_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :team] ]
    ].freeze

    def create
      build_resource(sign_up_params)
      if resource.meta_type == 'admin'
        resource.meta = Admin.new
      elsif resource.meta_type == 'original_user'
        resource.meta = OriginalUser.new
      end

      if resource.save
        render json: resource.payload
      else
        render json:
          bad_request_params(resource.errors), status: :bad_request
      end
    end

    protected

    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up,
                                        keys: KEYS_FOR_SIGNUP)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not use that scheme

```
KEYS_FOR_SIGNUP = %i[
    meta_type
    email
    password
    password_confirmation
    [ admin_attributes: [ :degree_access, :department] ]
    [ original_user_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :team] ]
].freeze
```

because you will get `:"[admin_attributes: [ :degree_access, :department]]"` instead expected behavior. You must use the plain array without literal `%i`